# How to go about making a itemsearch bar in ionic3 and firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I have a list with a searcher in ionic that filters the names of food products. It's made with the ionic searchbar and virtual scroll.

The only problem left is that I don't know the best practice for getting my 2000+ foodproduct names into my app. I've looked for the MySQL 'like' function in firebase but IT does not exist without using a paid version of elastic-search. I want to know of there are any other options. Could I Just get the whole list of 2000 items into my app as an observable? It might hit to 3000 items, but not many more. Or are there other options?

Thanks in regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was I used firebase cloud functions to use the value i pass with a http request to search my database with nodeJS like this:

```
exports.getFoodnames = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    const ref = admin.database().ref('foodnames');
    ref.once('value').then((snapshot)=> {
      let filtered_items = [];
      let searchTerm = request.query.search;

      snapshot.forEach(snap => {
        if (snap.val().name.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) filtered_items.push({ name : snap.val().name, $key: snap.key});
      });

      response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(filtered_items));
    });
  });
});
```

Hope I can help someone and please let me know if the code above can be made faster.